# Manipulate Strings in ArrayList Java

Tags: java

I have many string and i put it in a list.All the strings have this form:

\n   Ajax\n

\n   JavaScript\n

I just retreived from the server and i put in a list:

```
takedata.add(result.getBody().getTitle());
```

How can i cut the \n at both sides?

Comment: Is that a string of length two containing a slash and an n, or is it a newline character?

Comment: slash and n.I retrieve from a server and i put it in a list.And it put it with this form.And i want to delete the \n in both sides

Comment: @AlexDowining: Can you show us what already you have done before?

Comment: str.replaceAll("\n","");

Comment: Show us your code, how do you put the String in ArrayList..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("\n Ajax\n");
list.add("\n JavaScript\n");

for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
{
    String s = list.get(i).trim();
    list.set(i, s);
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

> I just retreived from the server with and i put in a list:

```
takedata.add(result.getBody().getTitle());
```

> How can i cut the \n at both sides?

Simply, use `trim()`:

```
takedata.add(result.getBody().getTitle().trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

The title says ArrayList, so

if you have `ArrayList<String> list`, you can use the method `replaceAll(String what, String withWhat)`

And the method should be called on `list.get(someIndex)`

IE> `list.get(1).replaceAll("\\n","")`  Remember you need to insert \ \ in order for java to read that you want to replace the \